# $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,0)}\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\text{Let }f(x,y)=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\text{ for } x^2+y^2<1.$$
$$\text{Show }\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,0)}f(x,y) \text{ does not exist.}$$

There's a hint to consider level curves $f(x,y)=c$ for $c$ a constant, but I'm not sure how this helps...

I did some rearranging and thought to consider when $x=1$.  Then $f(1,y)=\frac{y}{\sqrt{-y^2}}$ which DNE but this argument doesn't work because it doesn't specify that $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(1,0)$.  I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: My bad, I had the $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}$ when it should have been $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,0)}$

Answer (score 1):

On the path $x=t,y=0$ we have $$f(x,y)=f(t,0)=0\qquad \text{i.e.}\quad f(x,y)\to 0$$
On the $\color{red}{\text{ellipse}}$ $x=\sin t, y=\frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{2}}$ we have $(x,y)\to (1,0)$ as $t\to \frac{\pi}{2}^+$
$$f(x,y)=\frac{\frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{2}}}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2 t-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2 t}}=\frac{\frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{2}}}{\sqrt{\cos^2 t-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2 t}}=\frac{\frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{2}}}{\frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{2}}}=1\qquad \text{i.e.}\quad f(x,y)\to 1$$

It follows that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks! I always have trouble constructing a sequence that breaks the limit.  Now if the function were to change to $f(x,y)=\frac{y^m}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}, m\ge2$ would that have any difference on the limit?  I think it would because, using the same logic, $f(x,y)=\frac{\left(\frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^m}{\frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{2}}}=\left(\frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{m-1}\to0$ as $t\to\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: I found the answer... It doesn't work because if you consider $x=\sqrt{1-y^{2m}-y^2},x\to1$ as $y\to0$.  Then $f(\sqrt{1-y^{2m}-y^2},y)=\frac{y^m}{\sqrt{1-\left(\sqrt{1-y^{2m}-y^2}\right)^2-y^2}}=\frac{y^m}{y^m}=1\ne0$